# VBA : error 1004 - Selection and Copy issue

Tags: vba, copy

I need your help on something.. I have the 1004 error message (application or object non defined) when running the following code (I put only the critical parts) :

```
Sub overwrite_CDL()
Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Activate
Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A"
Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Mismatches").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'we want to create a summary sheet with the matches and the N/A:'
sht.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
sht.Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Instructions")).Name = "Summary DRP"
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Separately, everything works fine (no error messages, good output) but gives me the error 1004 when running together. The sheet I want to add is no created ("Summary DRP") even if the filters are set correctly.

I think the issue is related to the Selection / Copy but I don't know exactly why (I guess something is not defined properly..).

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which line returns the error?

Answer (score 1):

A few things....

Your code is hard to read without indents (that won't cause an error though).

- You set your last row on the currently active sheet, which may not be "JDE_Greece".
- After finding the last row, then you activate JDE_Greece.
- You copy the selection.
- You change sheets.
- You paste into whatever cells are selected on the `Mismatches` sheet (K36:Z36 on my sheet).
- You try and select the filtered to <>#N/A cells, but you haven't reselected the sheet yet so it can't select the cells and throws a `Select Method of Range class failed` error.

The moral of this story.... don't use Select.

So your code with nothing removed, but updated with comments:

```
Sub overwrite_CDL()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet '\\New variables

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mismatches") '\\Added reference to Mismatches.
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '\\Add sheet reference (not really necessary on Rows.Count as row counts should be the same across sheets).
    'sht.Activate  '\\Don't need to Activate or Select.
    sht.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A" '\\Add sheet reference.
    sht.Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '\\No need to Select, just copy.
    'Selection.Copy '\\Don't need this as incorported into above line.
    'Sheets("Mismatches").Select
    sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False  '\\Added sheet and cell reference.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'we want to create a summary sheet with the matches and the N/A:'
    '\\Moved these two lines after the new sheet is created.
    '\\sht.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
    '\\sht.Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    'Selection.Copy '\\Don't need this as incorported into above line.

    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'Add worksheet and use variable to reference it.
    sht2.Name = "Summary DRP"
    sht2.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions")

    'Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Instructions")).Name = "Summary DRP" '\\This row is now the above 3 rows.

    sht.Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
    sht.Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '\\No need to Select, just copy.

    sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False '\\Added sheet and cell reference.

End Sub
```

And tidied up:
NB:  I've removed the extra arguments you entered in the `PasteSpecial` - these are default values, so get set as that anyway.
Your code will still fail if 'Summary DRP' already exists.

```
Sub overwrite_CDL()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mismatches")

    With sht
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        .Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With sht2
        .Name = "Summary DRP"
        .Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions")
    End With

    With sht
        .Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
        .Range("A1:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to qualify `Rows` in `LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`  (**usually** won't matter, but probably best to tidy it while you are doing everything else)

Comment: I never know whether to qualify them or not - the number of rows on any worksheet should be the same, but I guess for completeness' sake they it should be in there.  I'll add it.

Comment: The issue usually arises if the user has two workbooks open.  Say `ThisWorkbook` is an older style xls file but the `ActiveWorkbook` is a new xlsx file.  `Rows.Count` (defaulting to `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`) would return `1048576`, but `sht.Cells(1048576, "A")` (where `sht` is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")` and therefore limited to 65536 rows) would give an error.

Comment: I've never thought of it that way, which is really silly seeing as IT at my work have set the default save on XL2010 to XLS so I regularly have those kind of problems (the best I've managed to work around it is `Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook` in my `Personal.xlsb` workbook_open event).

Comment: It's amazing the number of little "Ahah" moments we have while on SO.  I only got taught that reason for needing to qualify Rows.Count when I started hanging around here, just about a year ago.

Comment: Anyway - 9 p.m. - it's time to let you people on the other side of the world watch the questions while I catch some zzzzzs.

Comment: 9 p.m on a Friday an you're off to bed?!  Midday here and thinking about lunch and a late night tonight. :)

Comment: Guys, you're amazing !! Thanks a lot for this precious advices !! Big up also to Darren :) Have a nice day / night